# comment package : File ended while scanning use of \next

Tags: errors, comments

I have this very simple piece of code where I am trying to use the comment package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
    ABC
    \begin{comment}123\end{comment}
    XYZ
\end{document}
```

When I try to build it, I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

What is happening!?

Comment: From the documentation "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it."

Comment: I have updated the example just in case. It does not seem to change anything. It is still throwing the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't indent the begin and end-comment commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{comment}
    ABC
\end{comment}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh wow! Now I see, is this applicable only to the comments package? It definitely works but why? I never thought indentation makes any difference in latex

Comment: Normally it doesn't matter but comment is a rather special environment.